# No plot in RSweave document

Tags: r, sweave

Here is the code that is causing me some trouble ... Something does not seem to work within the plotting options of the chunks. Maybe my computer configuration is not the good one?

I have tried both methods of chunks 1 and 2 - I found them on other questions, but both fail, so I am a bit desperate now.

```
\begin{document} \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<Chunk 1,echo=TRUE,fig=TRUE>>= 
p <- qplot(mtcars$mpg)  
print(p) @

<<Chunk 2, echo=TRUE, fig=TRUE>>= 
plot(mtcars$mpg) @
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

Maxime.

Comment: You might have better luck using `knitr`. It's pretty much replaced `sweave`.

Comment: `qplot` is not base R. Have you imported the `ggplot2` package somewhere else in the code chunks? R does not load packages from the active session when compiling tex documents. This is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, unfortunately it does not seem to work: if I change Sweave into knitr in the global options, the compilation to pdf does not work. And even if I ad a line importing ggplot2, the same error occurs. Here are the warning messages I get : Warning messages:
1: file stem 'mychunk' is not portable 
2: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.3.3

Comment: NB: I just kept chunk 2 as you told me qplot is not R base.